# Enable/Disable unique constraint validation

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, unique-constraint

I was wondering if there is any way to enable or disable the validation of a `UNIQUE` constraint in PostgreSQL, or if there is some other way to allow duplicate records.

At the moment I am using a stored procedure which has a parameter `check duplicate`:

- If the argument is `true`, then the code runs `IF EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM table WHERE column = column_to_insert)` and throws a DuplicateKeyException.
- If `check duplicate` is `false`, it simply does the `INSERT`.

But I am suspecting that this solution is not race condition safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not safe, because there could be a concurrent transaction that

1. started before your `INSERT`
2. was not yet completed when the `IF EXISTS` check is run
3. inserts a conflicting row

Then you would end up with an unintended duplicate.

You could turn the `SELECT` into a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to make the window for the race condition smaller, but you cannot close it unless you use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level.

And the function does not protect you from anybody later inserting a duplicate for a value where you don't want it.

Maybe a `BEFORE` trigger and serializable transactions are the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was trying also with partial index solution but in a little bit different way with duplicate_check which was also a boolean, and it was working almost fine but there is a case that if I will add first a record with duplicate_check false and then duplicate_check true then it will go trough (as the duplicate_check false didn't hit the index), and next insertion with duplicate_check true will correctly fail. So I wanted to have more control over it with an option whether to check or not to check the entry.

Comment: You are right, my unique index is flawed. I'll change my answer.

Comment: Another solution I was thinking is basically add the partial unique index and insert always with TRUE and if DuplicateKeyException happens, based on the input of the stored procedure parameter is_duplicate_allowed, change the value to FALSE if duplicates are allowed otherwise throw the duplicate key exception